# Ruby on Rails Validation Issues for Multiple Fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, unique

I'm having some problem with validations for multiple fields, specifically with case-sensitive unique validations as well as the error message.

Let's say I want to ensure that the following field combinations are unique and are case-sensitive (Mary == mary) in my [Postgres] db:

```
user_id
first_name
last_name
```

As an example 
{4,Mary,Smith} 
{4,mary,Smith} 
should not save.

I know I need to do 2 things:
1.  Create unique index in db
2.  validate_uniqueness_of in my model

1. For the index, I created it though I did not find a way to ensure case-sensitivity (from my reading, it seems that MySQL is while Postgres is not).  I'll consider this done unless someone has an idea of how to do this.
2. I have the following code in my model:

```
     
   validates_uniqueness_of :user_id,
                :case_sensitive => false,
                :scope => [:first_name, :last_name],
                :if => :name_subcat_is_name?,
                :message => "You have already saved this contact information combination."
```

The problem is that the case-sensitivity seems to only apply to user_id, and not also first and last names.  So how can I apply case-sensitivity to the validation for all the fields?

Also, my error msg includes the name of the model:

**User** You have already saved this contact information combination.

I tried using yaml but it didn't remove the "User" class.
I found [this](http://lindsaar.net/2008/4/23/tip-14-custom-error-messages-in-validations) but don't know how to make it check all my fields rather than just one.  How can I add all the fields into a scope and see if that scope is ":taken"?

**UPDATE 1 June 24, 2012:**

Using my own validation method sounds like exactly what I need but I'm having some trouble implementing the code.  The MyModel.find(:first) method has been depreciated, so I tried substituting it with this:

```
existing_record = ContactInfo.where(:conditions => ["first_name ILIKE ? AND last_name ILIKE ?", first_name, last_name])
```

But when it gets to the next line
`unless existing_record.blank?`

I get an error:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  column contact_infos.conditions does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "contact_infos"  WHERE "contact_infos"....
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "contact_infos"  WHERE "contact_infos"."conditions" IN ('first_name ILIKE ? AND last_name ILIKE ?', 'mary', 'Smith')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define your own validation method to do this. It could look something like:

```
validate :user_id_uniqueness

def user_id_uniqueness
  return unless name_subcat_is_name?

  existing_record = MyModel.find(:first, :conditions => ["first_name ILIKE ? AND last_name ILIKE ?", first_name, last_name])
  unless existing_record.blank?
    errors.add(:user_id, "has already been saved in this contact information combination")
  end
end
```

('ILIKE' is specific to Postgresql)

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's exactly what I was writing as an answer ;-)

Comment: My bad - the query was incorrect.  When I rewrote it as:  existing_record = ContactInfo.where("contact_infos.first_name ILIKE ? AND contact_infos.last_name ILIKE ?", first_name, last_name) it works perfectly.  Thanks!